# Android Expandable lists having multiple child items in a single row and their onClick event

Tags: android, list, expandable

I could not figure out how to implement two basic functionalities with the expandable lists: 1. The onClick for the child 2. Using linear layout for the children, so that I can have multiple clickable items in same row under the parent item

Can somebody help me with some sample code for the above?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still interested - the google guys have written some very good samples for understanding and using expanable lists!

You can either use ExpandableListView (which extends ListView class), or simply create an [ExpandableListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html), which hosts an ExpandableListView.

Just take a look at these three examples. I made screenshots to show what it looks like (only notice that the background color isn't the one from the default theme):

[Example 1 - ExpandableList which receives data from a custom ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html)

[image]

[Example 2 - ExpandableList which receives data from a CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.html)

(no pic)

[Example 3 - ExpandableList which receives data from a simple HashMap-based Adapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList3.html)

[image]